# Using htaccess, Redirect http or https domain, and any subpage to particular page on another server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Background:

- We have DNS pointing to new server.
- Apache Server has a directory called example
- Example directory has an htaccess file for redirecting, code below

Issue is : We need this to redirect any variation of the url ie: http://example.com, https://example.com, http://example.com/filename.html, https://example.com/directory/filename.html, etc.. **to a specific page on another server.**

So far, we have the code below, it works correctly for https, but not http.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://differenturl/login/login.html [R=301,L]
```

I feel like there is a simple answer but can't seem to find it!
**Edit: for clarification -by not working, I mean that I am not redirected to https://differenturl/ etc... using http. It only works for https. http routes me to the home page of the server that this all sits on. And that server has a different domain name than anything above.

Comment: What happens when you request HTTP? What is the significance of the "directory called example" - is this the document root? The rule you posted also does not redirect `www.example.com` (ie. the www subdomain) - is that an issue? In fact, do you need to check the `Host` header at all? Are you hosting multiple domains on the first server?

Comment: thanks for your response. When I try accessing the http version, I am routed to the server home page... so :
-baseserver.com/example has the htaccess file. 
-The DNS for example.com points to baseserver.com/example (which is also setup with a virtual host)
-using the above htaccess, https://example.com/ redirects successfully to https://differenturl/ etc... as above
-using http://example.com/ I wind up at the root page of baseserver.com.

Comment: "The DNS for example.com points to baseserver.com/example" - Bear in mind that if there is another `.htaccess` file at `baseserver.com/` then this can also influence `example.com`, if `example.com` is pointing to a subdirectory of the main domain. (Strictly speaking `example.com` will be pointing to a _filesystem path_ - whether this happens to resolve to the same place as `baseserver.com/example` is not known to `example.com`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's "not working" for HTTP then either:

- The `<VirtualHost>` container for port 80 (ie. HTTP) is not configured at all in the server config.

Or,

- The vHost:80 container is pointing to a different area of the filesystem, so the `.htaccess` file is not processed.

Or,

- The vHost:80 container does not permit `.htaccess` overrides so the `.htaccess` file is ignored. You either need to configure `.htaccess` overrides by setting `AllowOverride All` in the appropriate `<Directory>` container in the vHost:80 container. Or simply redirect everything to HTTPS in the vHost:80 container (eg. `Redirect / https://example.com/`) and then allow the `.htaccess` file to redirect from HTTPS. (That's potentially 2 redirects, but that should not be an issue.)

  Or just do the redirect (to the other server) in the server config and not use `.htaccess` at all.

Comment: thanks, i am going to take a look at all that. Someone else did this part of the configuration, so I will check!

Comment: this seems to be the issue. The httpd config lists on port 443 for the redirect... thanks!

Comment: @LisaH _Aside:_ If the sole purpose of `example.com` is to redirect to the other domain then it's perhaps simpler to only use the server config (only a very minimal vHost config is then required). You then don't need the `example` subdirectory or `.htaccess` file (and no potential conflict from `baseserver.com`). The only possible caveat with that is if the redirect needs to change regularly, but since this is a 301 then I assume not (or updated by users that don't have access to the server config).

Comment: thanks again for your comments. The example.com server is used for a few different things. However, per your comment above, we looked at VirtualHost port 80... and this fixed it!